# How to grow gwt menuitem on hover

Tags: css, gwt, animation, menubar

So I have a gwt menu bar, and when I hover over an item, I want it to grow. The problem is that when I use css to modify the height of the hovered item, all the menu items get the effect. So when I hover over one menu item, all the menu items grow. Has anyone been able to use css to animate or transition on the menubar?

Here is my css:

```
.menuBar .gwt-MenuItem:hover {
 height: 30px;
 transition: height 1s;
-moz-transition: height 1s;/*  Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: height 1s; /* Opera  */
}
```

Here is what I want to accomplish, When my mouse hover over a menu item is will change size like in this image:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding your CSS to the [demo page at GWT Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar) and it worked. This is the selector I used: `.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItem:hover` I think you're just using a wrong selector?

Comment: it just made the item that was hovered grow and not the others?

Comment: I just tried using the same example and it is resizing all the menu items instead of just one @Churro

Comment: I'm sorry, are you trying to style the menu bar items, or the sub menu items?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work for the main menu items. It works fine for sub menu items. The issue is that the items are part of a table. If they were `<div>`s, they would pop out individually. [I'm guessing you're trying to accomplish something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/functionfirst/V4YaQ/1/)? There may be some combination of CSS properties that'll let you do it, but sorry, I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
.gwt-MenuBar-vertical .gwt-MenuItem:hover {
    /* properties applying to the vertical menu bar's menu items */
}
```

For more information, you can check the [css style rules of MenuBar](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html). Or check the [standard style of GWT widgets](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/Navigation/war/navigation/gwt/standard/standard.css?r=1239).